# Swipe to delete not working properly with custom XIB cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem with swipe delete function in UITableView with cell loaded from an XIB. As you can see below, when I swipe the cell to left image moves left but label doesn’t. So label covers delete button. Below you can find the code I have implemented:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //remove the deleted object from your data source.
        //If your data source is an NSMutableArray, do this
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MostKadroCell";

    MostKadroCell *cell = (MostKadroCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone]; 
    [cell.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled: NO]; //

    cell.lblKadroName.text = [arrKadroName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:strImage]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MostKadroCell" bundle:nil];
     [self.tableMostKadro registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MostKadroCell"];
     ....
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you may need to 'glue' the label to the left edge of the cell or to the `UIImageView` in the _Interface Builder_.

Comment: Use ``NSLayoutConstraint``'s to setup layout of your custom cell. You can add it in IB or in code.

Comment: Although I glued and used constraints from layout it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep label under(inside) the content view of the UITableView cell. Please check if its not out side the content view.

and add

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

View should seems likes 
[image]

Comment: When I put the label in the UIView, then the delete button goes behind the UIView. Also, it doesn't swipe to the left unlike the image view.

Comment: Can you please add the screen shot of the view hierarchy in the xib,  over here ?

Comment: when I modify it as you showed, the delete button goes behind the content view that means content view with label and imageview is not swiping to left.

Comment: please add the screen shot of your nib views